What is the path to the trashed content of the Samsung Gallery app?
On Samsung Android devices, I'm looking for the path to the trashed content of the Samsung Gallery app. Not Google Photos app.

If you trash a file in Samsung Gallery app it will be renamed and moved to
/sdcard/Android/.Trash/com.sec.android.gallery3d/<some_random_number>.<original file extension>

The file extension remains the same, but the name of the file before the extension dot is changed to a large ~18 digit random number.
Note that some file manager apps hide folders that start with a dot by default. Therefore you may not see the .Trash folder in some file managers (some have an option to temporarily or permanently show hidden files and folder which will reveal the .Trash folder).
Tested with Samsung Gallery app: v15.1.03.12 on Android 14
